# how can a Buefy toast be made available to all components in a Vue app?

Tags: vue.js, buefy

In a component in a Vue app the following method runs after a user clicks a Submit button on a form:

```
execute() {                    
            let message = '';
            let type = '';

            const response = this.actionMode == 'create' ? this.createResource() : this.updateResource(this.data.accountId);

            response.then(() => {
                message = 'Account ' + this.actionMode + 'd for ' + this.data.name;
                type = 'is-success';
            })
            .catch(e => {
                message = 'Account <i>NOT</i> ' + this.actionMode + 'd<br>' + e.message;
                type = 'is-danger';
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.displayOutcome(message, type);
                this.closeModal();
            });
        }
```

The `displayOutcome()` method in that same component looks like this:

```
displayOutcome(message, type) {
            this.$buefy.toast.open({
                duration: type == 'is-danger' ? 10000 : 3500,
                position: 'is-bottom',
                message: message,
                type: type
            });
        }
```

The code is working fine within the component.  Now I'm trying to move the `displayOutcome()` method into a helpers.js file and export that function so any component in the app can import it.  This would centralize maintenance of the toast and prevent writing individual toasts within each component that needs one.  Anyhow, when `displayOutcome()` gets moved over to helpers.js, then imported into the component an error appears in the console when the function is triggered:
[image]

I suspect it has to do with referring to the Vue instance so I experimented with the main.js file and changed this

```
new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

to this

```
var vm = new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

then in helpers.js

```
export function displayOutcome(message, type) {
    // this.$buefy.toast.open({
    vm.$buefy.toast.open({
        duration: type == 'is-danger' ? 10000 : 3500,
        position: 'is-bottom',
        message: message,
        type: type
    });
}
```

but that resulted in a "Failed to compile." error message.

Is it possible to make `displayOutcome()` in helpers.js work somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`displayOutcome()` requres a reference to `this` to work, which is fine if you define it as a method on your component object (the standard way). When you define it externally however, you just supply any **function** instead of a **method**, which is a function "targeted" on an object. This "targeting" is done through `this`. So when you're passing a simple function from an external file, there's no association to a specific object, and thus no `this` available.

To overcome this, you can use `displayOutcome.apply(thisArg, methodArgs)`, where `thisArg` will be whatever is the `this` reference in your function, and `methodArgs` are the remaining arguments that are being passed to the function.

So `displayOutcome.apply(4, ['some', 'thing'])` would imply that the `this` reference in `displayOutcome()` becomes `4` in this case.

Further reading:

- [Understanding "This" in JavaScript](https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding--this--in-javascript-du1084lyn)
- [`this` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

```js
import { displayOutcome } from './component-utils'

// when calling displayOutcome() from within your component
displayOutcome.apply(this, ['Hello World', 'is-info'])
```

```js
// component-utils.js
export function displayOutcome(message, type) {
    // this.$buefy.toast.open({
    this.$buefy.toast.open({
        duration: type == 'is-danger' ? 10000 : 3500,
        position: 'is-bottom',
        message: message,
        type: type
    });
}
```

Comment: Fantastic!  One minor adjustment was needed to get it to work: `displayOutcome.apply(this, ['Hello World', 'is-info'])`.  The console error message supplied sufficient guidance "...second argument to Function.prototype.apply must be an array".

Comment: Right, I always mix those two up. Thanks for pointing it out, I've updated the answer accordingly! FYI, there's another method besides apply - `.call()`, which doesn't accept an array but a list. `func.apply(myThis, [arg1, arg2])` vs `func.call(myThis, arg1, arg2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an action in Vuex store and dispatch it from any component.